# How to understand the percentage of backpressure in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to understand the meaning for backpressure percentage in Flink.

I think that it refers to the size of available buffer. But I don't get the precise meaning of it.

For example it has 80 percent of backpressured then what does it mean in precise ? I know that the general concept of backpressure in Flink but no way to understand to interpret the percentage of backpressured value even though I read the related articles.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Flink 1.13, an operator can be in one of three states:

- *idle*, meaning there is no data to process
- *backpressured*, meaning it is blocked, waiting for an output buffer
- *busy*, meaning it is neither idle or backpressured

If an operator is 80% backpressured, this means that the operator was backpressured for 800 ms during the past second.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For understanding it in low-level, where can I see those output buffer and percentage being calculated in the Flink module?

Comment: The webUI is requesting the `backPressuredTimeMsPerSecond` metric, and displaying it as a percentage. That metric is managed in org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.BufferWritingResultPartition.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/4a2f3a15903ca365c14368b34b30a6234a51aa5e/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/io/network/partition/BufferWritingResultPartition.java#L412